# Facebook Graph API /me/feed posts cannot change link picture size

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

My web app posts updates to Facebook users feed using the Graph API.  The API allows you to specify a text 'message' and '\n' in the text will result in a newline.  The API also allows one to specify a link url and link picture, which I have set to my app url and logo image.  One can also specify a link description, where '\n' in the text description does not result in a newline.

There are 2 unresolved issues for which I'm unable to find answers...

1) Facebook refuses to show the logo image in the post with a size less than 154x154.  I've tried submitting many size logos including larger, smaller, wider, higher.  Nothing results in an image anywhere near the 100x100 size I'd like to show.

2) The 154x154 image would be OK, if I could put newlines in the link description, which shows to the right of the square image.  It puts the text all on one line.  Tried '\n', '%0A', , padding with ' ', ...

Any idea how to solve #1 and if not... solve #2?